# Insert Google Analytics API data to postgresql [python]

Tags: python, postgresql, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to store bulk data to postgresql. 
The data I got are from google analytics [API]. The data is about pageviews and here is my code:

```
data = '[["20151201","path","title",345], ["20151202","path","title",321], ["20151203","path","title",214]]'

def storeJson( jsonFile, tableName ):
    conn = psycopg2.connect( host=hostname, user=username, password=password, dbname=database )
    try:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        # Here is the problem:
        cur.executemany( "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES(%s)", [jsonFile])
        conn.commit()

    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
        if conn:
            conn.rollback()
        print("Error %s" %e)
        exit()

    finally:
        if conn:
            cur.close()
            conn.close()

def main()
    storeJson(data, "daily_pageviews")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

with the code above, i got error message like this:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 12 (char 11)

Can someone enlighten me? Thanks guys!

Comment: can you add your `create table` command here? Do you need to insert data as json or parse it before insertion?

Comment: I think there are no problem with table since the error isn't about database. Here is my create table query anyway:
create table daily_pageviews(
"date" date,
path text,
title text,
pageviews int )

Answer (score 0):

*`jsonFile` is a string* in your case. You need to load it with `json.loads()`:

```
import json

data = json.loads(jsonFile)
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)", data)
```

Note that I have *4 placeholders* in the query - each for every item in every sublist.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now I got error: "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting".

Comment: @Wenhui my bad, fixed. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, here is the case: First, my data isn't json format but it is list of list format. Here is the solution I got from my friend using sqlalchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.schema import MetaData, Table

engine = create_engine('postgresql://db_username:db_password@ip/dbname')

metadata = MetaData()
metadata.bind = engine

def storeJson( jsonFile, tableName ):
    table = Table(tableName, metadata, autoload=True)
    #import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    def to_dicts(rows):
        for row in rows:
            data = {}
            for i, column in enumerate(table.columns):
                data[column.name] = row[i]
            yield data
    params = list(to_dicts(jsonFile))
    engine.execute(table.insert(), params)
    return
```

Assuming value of jsonFile list ordered exactly like the table on db.
**Note:** You could install sqlalchemy using pip

> python -m pip install sqlalchemy --user

As for "how to" get data from google analytics, you could visit it's site: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py